# clause as the modifier to the object of a verb

Tags: grammar

The following sentence seems to lack "that", which is necessary as it is the subject of the clause "(that) exist everywhere".

> You need to make quick sense of **data relationships exist everywhere**.

[from a tutorial](https://youtu.be/_D19h5s73Co?t=99)

"data relationships" is the object of the phrasal verb "make quick sense of".

Is my understanding right?

Comment: It doesn't say "You need to ...". It says "**The** need to make ..." and that is fine without "that". You seem to have missed a few other things. // The [need] to [make **quick** sense of data relationships] [exist**s** everywhere]. //

Comment: No: "data relationships that exist everywhere" is a noun phrase functioning as object of the preposition "of".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Data relationships exist everywhere" is a sentence in its own right, and cannot be treated as a noun phrase. "Data relationships" is a phrase whose usage in this context is a noun. "Exist everywhere" is a predicate which directly qualifies "data relationships".

So you need "that" so as to convert the predicate "exist everywhere" into an adjectival phrase, and you do that by qualifying it with "that", which gives "exist everywhere" something to act on.

Having created your adjectival phrase "that exist everywhere", you now have to decide whether or not to separate it from "You need to make quick sense of data relationships" with a comma or not.

The difference is subtle.

In "You need to make quick sense of data relationships, that exist everywhere", the listener is being advised to make quick sense of *all* data relationships. The phrase "that exist everywhere" adds extra information to the data relationships. (They are everywhere.)

In "You need to make quick sense of data relationships that exist everywhere", the noun phrase is now the compound "data relationships that exist everywhere".

Which data relationships do I need to make quick sense of? Only the ones that exist everywhere.

In this context, it would appear that the version *with* the comma is probably what is meant.

(In fact, in this context I would be happier to use the word "which" rather than "that", but I fear I may be on shaky ground.)

Comment: You wasted your time. The OP made a mistake in quoting the author. Check the YouTube link the OP posted.

Comment: Yeah my bad, Life's too short to waste it on such fripperies.

Comment: I'm so sorry to mislead you. I quoted that from the official transcript which looks like well-organized. Still, I learned something informative from your answer. Thank you so much. Btw, does "fripperies" mean "showy or unnecessary ornament in architecture, dress, or language" there?

Comment: Yes, it's my chosen rhetorical style to refer to something as a "pointless waste of time". Do not take this too seriously, I understand some people get a lot out of YouBend, but as for me, as a learning tool I despise it.

Comment: Non-defining relatives (the kind with a comma) always have a _wh_ relative word, never "that", so your example "You need to make quick sense of data relationships, that exist everywhere" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, that may of course depend on whether you're talking about English or American. I know the usage differs depending upon which particular language is under discussion.

Comment: You're thinking of the relative word in a defining relative clause such as "This is the key **that/which** she found, where AmE prefers which", while BrE is happy with either "which" or "that". But I'm talking about non-defining relatives like your example *"You need to make quick sense of data relationships, that exist everywhere", which is ungrammatical for all speakers because "that" is not allowed in non-defining relatives.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not sure I agree with the "not allowed" descriptor here.

Answer (score -1):

> *You need to make quick sense of* [*data relationships exist everywhere*].

The sequence "exist everywhere" is intended to be a relative clause modifying "data relationships", but the subordinator "that" or the relative pronoun "which" has been omitted in error.

The whole bracketed noun phrase is object of the preposition "of" (not of "make quick sense of").